# '?' and ':' in C language

Tags: c

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    int max = a > b ? a : b;
    max = c > max ? c : max;
    max = d > max ? d : max;
    return max;
}
```

so this is the code I found on net I was gonna write the greatest number what does this code mean or '?' and ':' mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator

Comment: IMO, that's obscurely written code.  Using the ternary operator like that is not good.  The first line in the body of the function is OK.  The other two could be written `if (c > max) max = c; if (d > max) max = d;`.  And the generalization to the maximum of an array of values is probably written like `int max = a[0]; for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) { if (a[i] > max) max = a[i]; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre looking at "ternary" operators.  They typically work of the form

`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

So to translate `c > max ? c : max;` to a traditional if:

`if (c > max) { return c } else return max;`

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".